# front-page.php is not Listing in Static Front Page List

Tags: theme-development

I have a    [image] in my theme directory and I would like to set the WP to be static based on page. I didnt create any pages so far because my assumption was the  [image] must be listed as a page in the front page display list but it is not!

Do I have to explicitly create a Page with [image] template and then set as Front Page? 
 [image]

was't that Front Page pointed to  [image] automatically? or I am missing something?!

Comment: If you want your `front-page.php` as your home page then you have to select "Your latest posts" option from `settings -> readings` instead of "A static front page" option and save changes. And also what content is showing on front page right now? is it content of index.php 's file or what?

Comment: Thanks Rishabh, but I am trying to create a website with static pages!

Comment: Then you have to create a page in `dashboard -> Add pages` and go to settings -> readings and there choose newly created page on option "A static page" as simple as that, I am not getting whats issue you are facing in this.

Comment: please take a look at this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Custom_Site_Front_Page_Template

Comment: but I can not find the`front-page.php` in `dashboard -> Add pages-->Template` list. so how can I set a page as the  `front-page.php`?

Comment: Try to give your `front-page.php` a template name. For that open your front-page.php and in first line of your file inside php tags add name like this `/* Template Name: Give Any Name*/`. Name must be given in comments. Now you can see your given name in dashboard -> add pages in right side under template option.

Answer (score 0):

This front-page.php is flie templates.
You need to select page for front page(This display first page = homepage).

Your homepage display same design